# GitHub Action [cypress CI integration ]: How to set env variables before running cypress run command

Tags: javascript, continuous-integration, cypress, github-actions

I am writing workflows for my repository, and I want to run test cases whenever there is a code push.

Here is the code snippet from .yml file:

```
  - name: Run cypress test
    with:
      env: true
    env:
      username: ${{secrets.CYPRESS_USERNAME}}
      password: ${{secrets.CYPRESS_PASSWORD}}
    
    run: npm run cy:test --env fileConfig=production, username=$username, password=$password 
    continue-on-error: false
```

Snippet from JSON :

```
{

"env": {
    "userId": "1",
    "environment": "production",
    "baseUrl": " base URL"
    }
}
```

So, I want to pass the username and password along with the configfile in the cypress run command so that they can be set as the env variable because I am using username and password for my login test module.

With the above code i am getting error :

*The workflow is not valid. .github/workflows/main.yml (Line: 43, Col: 9): Unexpected value 'run' .github/workflows/main.yml (Line: 36, Col: 9): Required property is missing: uses*

Thanks :)

Comment: I think the problem is not in the cypress run command, but in that you're missing `uses` property in the YAML file. Perhaps this will help https://github.com/cypress-io/github-action

Comment: I tried to use 'uses; property but it says - a step cannot have both the `uses` and `run` keys

Comment: Cypress has its own github actions plugin, take a look and try it https://docs.cypress.io/guides/continuous-integration/github-actions.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to add the env variables as empty strings on **cypress.json**:

```
{

  "env": {
    "userId": "1",
    "environment": "production",
    "baseUrl": "base URL",
    "username": "",
    "password": ""
  }
}
```

In main.yml file, you need to add the CYPRESS_ prefix to the variables:

```
env:
  CYPRESS_username: ${{secrets.CYPRESS_USERNAME}}
  CYPRESS_password: ${{secrets.CYPRESS_PASSWORD}}
```

Also, you should use the setup that can be found on cypress docs (https://docs.cypress.io/guides/continuous-integration/github-actions#Basic-Setup), example:

```
name: Cypress Tests

on: [push]

jobs:
  cypress-run:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      # Install NPM dependencies, cache them correctly
      # and run all Cypress tests
      - name: Cypress run
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v2
        with:
          build: npm run build
          start: npm start
        env:
          CYPRESS_username: ${{secrets.CYPRESS_USERNAME}}
          CYPRESS_password: ${{secrets.CYPRESS_PASSWORD}}
```

You should also read this article: https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/keep-passwords-secret-in-e2e-tests/